# Hiding multiple implementations behind a single interface

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, cmake

I know about the Strategy and Abstract Factory design patterns - however they don't solve my current problem:

I'm creating a C++ library that offers a very basic GUI. However I want the user to be able to choose at compile time which GUI library to use (say Qt or FLTK) to actually render the GUI. The user should however only need to know about the methods in my library.

It should be possible to compile the same code without any changes using either a Qt backend or an FLTK backend.

I thought of something like:

```
class A
{
  // do things that are not specific to QT or FLTK here as there are many 
  // methods I will need independent of the backend
}

class QT_A : public A
{
  // Implement the actual creation of a window, display of a widget here using Qt
}

class FLTK_A : public A
{
  // Implement the actual creation of a window, display of a widget here using FLTK
}
```

The problem is that I do not want the user to know about `QT_A` or `FLTK_A`. The user (developer) should just deal with `A`. Also, I can't have both variants at the same time as I don't want my library to depend on both Qt and FLTK; just whichever was chosen at compile time.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to use the pre-processor... I hope you get a better answer.

Comment: It's not called QT but Qt (QT = QuickTime, Qt = cute ;) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is the Pimpl idiom described in another answer.

Another option is a factory returning a pointer to the interface class:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> make_A()
{
#if defined(USING_QT)
    return std::unique_ptr<A>(new QT_A(...));
#elif defined(USING_FLTK)
    return std::unique_ptr<A>(new FLTK_A(...));
#else
    #error "No GUI library chosen"
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The Pimpl idiom may be an alternative. It allows you to create a common interface without framework dependent members.

```
class A
{
  struct impl;
  std::unique_ptr<impl> pimpl; // or scoped_ptr/auto_ptr on non-C++11
public:
  A();
  ~A();
 void do_sth();
};
```

Then, the source file can provide different implementations of impl depending on the backend.

```
#ifdef QT
struct A::impl : QWidget { // Make it polymorphic, if you need
  QImage img;
  QString data;
};

void A::do_sth()
{
  impl->make_it(); // full access to the Qt things
}

A::A()
  : pimpl(new ...)
{
}

A::~A() {} // no need for delete thanks the smart pointer

#endif
```

Comment: wait, you have a pointer to a pointer to a `QWidget`, this isn't _quite_ how pimpl usually works.

Comment: True but it's how Qt works (sadly). I will make a better example.

Answer (score 3):

No need of fancy patterns.

You distribute

1. headers of A;
2. a library that contains `A`, `QT_A`, and `make_A` function;
3. another library that contains `A`, `FLTK_A` and another implementation of `make_A` function.

The user links to either library.

Comment: Patterns are 'fancy'? seriously? the Gang of Four was 19 years ago and was voted the most important book of the decade... time to come out of the cave...

Comment: @Rob: I have read the book the year it was published. It's actually quite good, but none of it is needed here, hence "fancy". Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand... If the headers of A are used then only instances of A would be created by i need an instance of the respective derived class (QT_A or FLTK_A).

Comment: `A.h` has the `A* makeA();` *declaration*. The two *definitions* are in `QT_A.cpp` and `FLTK_A.cpp`. They return pointers to `QT_A` and `FLTK_A` respectively, cast to `A*`. The user is not supposed to link both libraries so there's no conflict.