# Hide multiple (given) implementations behind an interface

Tags: java, interface

There are a few Matrix libraries out there, each with their goods and bads - so i decided that for now i'd like to use a common interface so that i can easily switch one library for another later on.

What i have is something like:

```
public interface IMatrix {
   public IMatrix add(IMatrix matrix);
   public IMatrix multiply(IMatrix matrix);
   ...
}
```

And in the code:

```
IMatrix someMatrix = MatrixFactory.createDenseMatrix(3,5); 
//I'm using a MatrixFactory to hide the different implementation constructors
```

As an example, say i want to implement this IMatrix using the base classes from EJML and La4j.
I thought of two solutions, none perfect:

### Solution 1 - creating a wrapper around the base class:

This seems to work, even if a little cumbersome:

```
class SimpleMatrixInside implements IMatrix{
    private final SimpleMatrix matrix;

    SimpleMatrixInside(SimpleMatrix m) {
        matrix = m;
    }

    @Override
    public IMatrix add(IMatrix someMatrix) {
        SimpleMatrixInside toSum = (SimpleMatrixInside)someMatrix;
        return new SimpleMatrixInside(matrix.plus(toSum.matrix));
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int row, int col, double val) {
        this.matrix.set(row,col, val);
    }

    @Override
    public IMatrix multiply(IMatrix matrix) {
        SimpleMatrix toMultiply= ((SimpleMatrixInside)matrix).matrix;
        return new SimpleMatrixInside(this.matrix.mult(toMultiply));
    }
```

### Idea 2 - extending the base class:

This seems like a bad idea since class methods could be overridden and anyway its methods would return the wrong type of object - i don't know how this could work.

```
class La4jDenseMatrix extends Basic2DMatrix implements IMatrixPar {
 @Override
    public IVector multiply(IMatrix matrix) {
        return this.mult(matrix);
        }
}
```

---

I think **Solution 1** is the only way to do this - are there other, better ways?

Related question for C++: [Hiding multiple implementations behind a single interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486080/hiding-multiple-implementations-behind-a-single-interface)

Comment: I know that it is purely subjective, but note that the hungarian notation is redundant and quite rare anyways in Java (with few notable exceptions).

Comment: What kind of notation do you suggest?

Comment: You should use `Matrix` instead of `IMatrix`. Which is the norm: you find `List`, `Map` etc., not `IMap`, `IList`...

Comment: @Enoon Solution 1 also allows you to use multiple implementation classes at once! Imagine a case where different implementations handle different matrix sizes better. Based on the constructor arguments, you could actually return different implementations to optimize the matrix operations!

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo ah, yes. I called it IMatrix for less confusion with the La4J Matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, solution 1 is the right way to go. This has the distinct advantage of giving you the control of how to map each implementation class' API to IMatrix.

Imagine two different APIs that have similar functionality, but different method calls. The only way to normalize this is exactly what you propose in suggestion 1.